# Get unordered unique elements from two lists python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

if i have two lists (may be with different len):

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]

result = > [11, 22, 33, 44]
```

doing:

```
for element in x:
    if element in f:
        f.remove(element)
```

getting

```
result = [11,22,33,44,4]
```

**set** method return ordered collection but i need to keep order of elements.

is there better way to do that?

Comment: Why is `4` included in the result?

Comment: golden rule: don't mutate what you're iterating over

Comment: What you are doing is different than doing the set operation of the unique elements from lists https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `set` operations? This is going to generate a sorted list, which is independent to the provided order:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]
>>> sorted(set(f) - set(x))
[11, 22, 33, 44]
```

Answer (score 6):

Editing a list while iterating over it is bad practice, but here's a list comprehension to do what you want.  This will keep the order as well.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]
>>> [a for a in f if a not in set(x)]
[11, 22, 33, 44]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid removing elements of a list while looping through it. Making a copy helps.

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
f = [1, 11, 22, 33, 44, 3, 4]
f2 = f.copy()
for element in f2:
    if element in x:
        f.remove(element)

print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you iterate the list from bottom to top, you will get the correct result:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
f = [1,11,22,33,44,3,4]

for i in range(len(f)-1, -1, -1):
    if f[i] in x:
        f.pop(i)        

print(f)  # [11, 22, 33, 44]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one line code, you will get the result

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
f = [1, 11, 22, 33, 44, 3, 4]
print(sorted(set(f).difference(set(x))))

output: [11, 22, 33, 44]
```